# Multiple Counters(Incrementing Number using JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, frontend

I want to make a multiple counters that will keep on increasing until the limit that is specified inside a dataset attribute is reached and put it inside a div, and I want to see the number increasing on time. **I also want it to be a reusable function**

I'm stuck in making increase and putting it inside a divs.

Html:

```
 <div class="amount" data-num="100"></div>
 <div class="amount" data-num="55"></div>
 <div class="amount" data-num="90"></div>
 <div class="amount" data-num="65"></div>
```

```
const amounts = document.querySelectorAll('.amount');
      const limits = [...amounts].map(amount => amount.dataset.num)
      const counts = 0;
      
      
      function counter() {
        while (counts < limits) {
          counts = counts + 1
          amounts.textContent += + counts +;
        }
      }
```

javascript, js, html, frontend, vanilla JS

Comment: `amounts.textContent += + counts +;` will not work as you expected

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example thats fully commented.

I don't quite understand exactly what you'd like to do, but this example has all the pieces you need to create what you're describing.

`setTimeout( functionName, time )` allows you to set a timer, the time is calculated in milliseconds (so 1 second is 1000).

I've stored the limits within the attributes of multiple divs and then checked these by cycling through all divs with the class `.limit`, before comparing their `data-limit` attribute to that of the `counter` variable.

**Update**
Have now used `setInerval` so that you can start, stop and reset. Everything is commented.

```js
// Create array of limits
limits = [2, 5, 6, 9]

// Create counter
counter = 0

// Create divs for each limit
limits.forEach(function(key, value) {

  // Add class .limit for easy identification
  // Store limit in data-limit attribute
  document.getElementById('limitList').innerHTML += "<div>" + key + "<span  data-limit='" + key + "' class='limit'></span></div>";

});

// Counter function
function increaseCounter() {

  // Increase counter
  counter += 1;

  // Display counter
  document.getElementById("displayCount").innerHTML = counter;

  // Get remaining limits
  remainingLimits = document.querySelectorAll(".limit:not(.limit-met)");


  // Check each limit div, skip if limit met class present
  remainingLimits.forEach(function(el) {


    // If limit equals count
    if (el.getAttribute("data-limit") == counter) {

      // Append text
      el.append(" \u2713");

      // Mark as met via class
      el.classList.add("limit-met");

    }

  });

  // Check if there are remaining limits
  if (remainingLimits.length === 0) {

    // Stop the timer if there aren't any
    clearInterval(myCounter);

  }

}

// Start counter by default
var myCounter = setInterval(function() {
  increaseCounter()
}, 1000);


// Reset button
document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function() {


  // Reset counter
  counter = 0;

  // Reset display counter
  document.getElementById("displayCount").innerHTML = counter;

  // Get met limits
  metLimits = document.querySelectorAll(".limit-met");

  // Remove met-limit class
  metLimits.forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.remove("limit-met");
    el.innerHTML = "";
  });

  // Restart timer
  clearInterval(myCounter); // Pause if already running to prevent double coutning
  myCounter = setInterval(function() {
    increaseCounter()
  }, 1000);


}


// Start button
document.getElementById("start").onclick = function() {

  // Restart timer
  clearInterval(myCounter); // Pause if already running to prevent double coutning
  myCounter = setInterval(function() {
    increaseCounter()
  }, 1000);

}


// Stop button
document.getElementById("stop").onclick = function() {

  // Stop timer
  clearInterval(myCounter);

}
```

```css
.limit {
  color: red;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 12px;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.limit {
  margin-left: 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.limit-met {
  color: green;
  border-color: green;
}

button {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 12px 0px 0px 12px;
}

#start {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <button id='reset'>Reset</button>
  <button id='stop'>Stop</button>
  <button id='start'>Start</button>

  <div class='wrapper'>
    <span>Counter:</span>
    <div id='displayCount'>0</div>
  </div>

  <div id='limitWrapper' class='wrapper'>
    <span>Limits:</span>
    <div id='limitList'>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: what about in vanilla JS?

Comment: The only use of jquery was auto generating the divs rather than any of the comparison/counter logic, but have updated to show only vanilla JS.

Comment: so this will work now, without the script tag of jquery?

Comment: Try the code snippet! Click on `Run code snippet` and you can see it run :)

Comment: the counter is working, but i want multiple counters. i made my question more clear above **please check my html code** . thanks

Comment: Have updated to a much more complex scenario that can be paused, restarted, etc. You dont need multiple counters unless their time interval is different. You should have a single `setInterval` that updates anything that is needed. This has all the pieces you need to create your desired use-case.